# Express route test with Supertest and Mocha failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

I have a set of tests to verify that my Express serves routes properly. For one of my routes `launch.js`, I receive two different errors, and sometimes the test randomly passes with long (425ms+) response times. Is there a better way to approach this?

**launch.js**

```
const authUtils = require('../../lib/authUtils');
const express = require('express');
const VError = require('verror');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  /**
   * Request conformance object
   */
  authUtils.getConformance((error, response, body) => {
    // If error with HTTP request
    if (error) {
      throw new VError('Conformance object request failed', error);
    // If error from auth server
    } else if (response.body.message) {
      throw new VError('Conformance object request failed', response.body.message);
    // If request for conformance object succeeds
    } else {
      // Parse conformance object for tokenUri and authUri
      authUtils.parseConformanceUris(body, (authUri, tokenUri, parsingError) => {
        // Ensure URIs can be parsed from response
        if (error) {
          throw new VError('Issue while parsing conformance object', parsingError);
        } else {
          /**
           * Data values needed later for /redirect
           * @type {{state: string, tokenUri: string}}
           */
          const launchData = {
            state: authUtils.getUniqueCode(),
            tokenUri,
          };

          // Build URI to request token from auth server
          authUtils.buildGetTokenUri(authUri, launchData.state, (getTokenUri) => {
            // Store state and tokenUri to session and redirect browser
            authUtils.storeLaunchData(req, res, launchData, getTokenUri);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**index.spec.js**

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../index');

describe('Express server routes', () => {
  describe('GET /launch', () => {
    it('responds with HTTP 302', (done) => {
      request(app).get('/launch').expect(302, done);
    });
  });
});
```

**subject.getConformance**

```
/**
 * Utility function to request conformance object from auth server
 * @param callback
 */
const getConformance = (callback) => {
  request({ url: process.env.CONFORMANCE_URI, json: true, method: 'get' }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      callback(null, response, body);
    } else {
      callback(error, response, null);
    }
  });
};
```

**Error 1**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null
>         at subject.getConformance (test/authUtils.spec.js:28:27)
>         at Request.request [as _callback] (lib/authUtils.js:7:374)
>         at Request.self.callback (node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
>         at Request. (node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
>         at IncomingMessage. (node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
>         at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
>         at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

**Error 2**

> Uncaught AssertionError: expected 'body' to equal undefined
>         at subject.getConformance (test/authUtils.spec.js:43:16)
>         at Request.request [as _callback] (lib/authUtils.js:7:374)
>         at Request.self.callback (node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
>         at Request. (node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
>         at IncomingMessage. (node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
>         at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
>         at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the app object is requiring from a expressjs server, try

```
.get('/launch')
      .expect(302)
      .end(function (err, res) {
        res.status.should.be.equal(302);
        done();
      });
```

If your index.js file is not a server then you need to configure the `app` object from a valid server. Are you exporting the `app` from index.js where `app` is

```
var express = require("express")
    , app = express();
```

?

Comment: Yes, this is how `index.js` is configured, as the Express server.

I am actually receiving a 500 status code because the testing suite is apparently trying to run the logic within my route (as an integration test). I understand this, but what I don't understand is why the assert test passes when the two values are not equal.

Comment: Where is the assert in your test?